# Are the imaginary units of complex numbers anyhow related to vectors?

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors

I have studied **introductory** vector for use in physics ( introduction to vectors, products of vectors) that have vectors defined by unit vectors $ \hat{i} ,  \hat{j} , \hat{k} $
And i have also read about complex numbers of the form $a + ib$, which simply defines a point in plane.
I want to know are the two things related to each other, if yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complex numbers can be used in 2D geometry, but do not generalize to 3D. There is a generalization to 4D, called *quaternions*.

Vectors can be defined with any number of dimensions, and important cases are 2D and 3D. Algebra on vectors and on complex numbers partially overlap, but not much.

Comment: +1, since this is the only answer so far that hints at the actual historical reason for why the unit vectors are denoted by $\hat{i},\hat{j},\hat{k}$. But it could perhaps have used a bit more explanation: a quaternion has the form $a+ib+jc+kd$ where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbf{R}$ and $i,j,k$ are imaginary units satisfying $i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$, and $a$ is called the *scalar part* of the quaternion and $ib+jc+kd$ is the *vector part* (Hamilton introduced the word “vector” in the context of quaternions). And so on.

Comment: Quaternions can be thought of as 3D. The Real part is treated as a scalar instead of a vector, and the imaginary part as a bivector instead of a vector.

Comment: @HansLundmark I also agree on that with you

Comment: @mr_e_man can you please explain what is a bivector mean?

Comment: @Adi -- A bivector is a "wedge product" of two vectors. It represents a plane, just as a vector represents a line. In 2D, there is only one plane ($xy$). In 3D, there are 3 coordinate planes ($xy,xz,yz$), and their bivectors multiply in the same way as quaternions. The basic rules are $\hat x\hat x=1$ , $\hat x\hat y=-\hat y\hat x$ , $\hat y\hat y=1$, etc., so that $$(\hat x\hat y)^2=(\hat x\hat y)(\hat x\hat y)=\hat x(\hat y\hat x)\hat y=\hat x(-\hat x\hat y)\hat y=-(\hat x\hat x)(\hat y\hat y)=-1,$$ and $(\hat x\hat y)(\hat y\hat z)=\hat x\hat z$ , and so on. See "geometric algebra".

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a very cool embedding of the complex numbers into the vector space of $2 \times 2$ matrices over the real numbers. The mapping is as follows: $$a+bi \rightarrow aI + b \begin{bmatrix}0&-1 \\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ with $I$ being the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix. The eigenvalues of the matrix representing the imaginary part are also $\pm i$ as well which has always seemed rather elegant to me. The two structures reflect each other naturally.

Answer (score 1):

No. $\hat i=(1,0,0)$, $\hat j=(0,1,0)$, $\hat k=(0,0,1)$ and $i=(0,1)$ if defined as a point of complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

No the two things are not related at all and notably $i\neq \hat i$.

Anyway in the compex plane the imaginary unit $i$ can be considered in correspondence with the unit vector $\hat j=(0,1)$ as any other complex number $$z=x+iy=(x,y)=x(1,0)+y(0,1)=x\hat i + y \hat j$$